# Customising a url after page loads

Tags: javascript

My website's url is a bit untidy due to the query strings.

```
www.myweb.com/main/page.html?category=fruits&section=a6d&id=539
```

Once the page loads is there a way to change the url in to something very new?

e.g.: `www.myweb.com/fruits`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Maybe something like www.myweb.com/fruits/a6d/539 unless the section and ID are not required